# How I can translate first and then rotate when translation completes in css?

Tags: jquery, css

I want `thisdiv` to be tranlated first then rotate, but I have no idea how I can do this??
Here are my codes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(".thisdiv").css("transform", "translateX(200px) rotate(30deg)");
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.thisdiv {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="thisdiv">
    This is div
  </div>
</div>
```

Also I want `thisdiv` to be rotated and translated only in **large viewports (laptop or desktop)** but not in small viewports (mobiles). In **small viewport** it should be **remain in the center** without any animations.

Comment: use CSS animation

Comment: you have to use CSS animations

Comment: You don't _have_ to use CSS animations for this, as it can also be done with JQuery animation.  Without understanding the requirement further, it's difficult to advise how to achieve the aim though

Comment: I have updated my query. Now It may be easy to answer.

Comment: TemaniAfif, Shayan I don't often use css animation so It would be difficult with that. Can you answer your codes?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this. First you set margin-left:0px; and then wait for 2000ms (2seconds)(You can adjust this), then add class('move') to move to right 2000px and then wait for (3000ms) (Of course you can adjust this also), then add class('rotate')

The tricky point is the second function which will be trigger when the transition end, which means trigger the move animation end.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function(){ 
$(".thisdiv").addClass('move');
}, 2000);
  $(".thisdiv").one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', 
function() {
setTimeout(function(){ 
$('.thisdiv').addClass('rotate'); 
}, 3000);
 
});
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.thisdiv {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  margin-left:0px;
}

.thisdiv.move{
margin-left:200px;
}

.thisdiv.rotate{
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="thisdiv">
    This is div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the only one way to achieve your expectation. You can also try to use jquery animation which can be also achieve

Comment: This is a good approach but this is not what I wanted. I want to wait only when page loads, after that translate and rotate without waiting.

Comment: I can't use margin. I don't want `thisdiv` to affect another elements in document.

Comment: "after that translate and rotate without waiting", Then, what is the meaning of tranlated first then rotate?

Comment: I mean translate and rotate suddenly

Comment: If you write `$('.thisdiv').addClass('rotate'); ` out of setTimeout() function, that's the result I want. Here don't need to add timeout.